# What goes on in an AC circuit when the power delivered to the inductor is negative?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, power, inductance

The instantaneous power delivered to a resistor by an alternating voltage source $v(t)=V_0\sin\omega t$, is always nonnegative. But the instantaneous power delivered to an inductor by $v(t)=V_0\sin\omega t$, is positive for $0<\omega t<\pi/2$ and negative for $\pi/2<\omega t<\pi$.

During the first quarter of the cycle ($0<\omega t<\pi/2$), both $v_L(t)$ and $i(t)$ have the same signs, and the power delivered to the inductor is positive. This energy is stored in the inductor as magnetic energy. In the next quarter of the cycle ($\pi/2<\omega t<\pi$), $v_L(t)$ and $i(t)$ have the opposite signs, the power delivered to the inductor is negative! I do not understand this part of the cycle in terms of what the circuit is doing.

During this interval, is the magnetic energy stored in the inductor negative? What would that mean?

During this interval, the inductor delivers power to the source? How does an inductor deliver power to the source?

Comment: One of the most common tricks in modern electronics is to use an inductor as an energy transfer device. Push energy into it from a source, and then switch its connections so it delivers its energy to a load. The source and load voltages need not be the same if the timing isn't symmetric, so you may convert high voltage to low or vice-versa. Doing this quickly using a relatively small inductor makes a power supply that's much smaller and less expensive than the low frequency transformer tech of the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> During this interval, the inductor delivers power to the source? How does an inductor deliver power to the source?

Yes, by doing work against the electrostatic field of the voltage source.

An inductor can accept work of the voltage source and store it as magnetic energy at one time interval (while the current magnitude increases and goes in the direction of potential drop), and at other time interval, it can release this magnetic energy by doing work on mobile charges running through it (current magnitude decreases and goes in opposite direction to the potential drop).

When an inductor releases energy via work back to the source, this work is done by induced electric forces ( due to the induced electric field of the inductor) acting on the mobile charge carriers in direction of their motion. Since these charge carriers' kinetic energy remains negligible all the time, all this work is spent to increase electric potential energy of all the charges. In other words, the induced electric field forces deliver positive work against the forces of conservative electric field, and this work is stored (usually) as increased electrostatic energy of those charges in the source and on surfaces of all circuit elements, including the inductor. In other words, magnetic energy turns into electric energy.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Passive Sign Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention), when the power associated with a passive circuit element is negative, that circuit element is a power *source*, i.e., it is supplying energy to the circuit.

This makes sense when you think carefully about it. Since the (ideal) inductor does not dissipate energy, the inductor must return to the circuit the energy it absorbs during the sinusoidal cycle. Thus, we would expect the inductor to have positive power during 1/2 the cycle (and the stored magnetic energy to be *increasing*) and negative power during the other 1/2 cycle (and the stored magnetic energy to be *decreasing*).

This ensures that the *net* energy delivered to the inductor is zero. Note that this is the essence of the concept of *reactive* power where the energy 'sloshes' back and forth between the inductor and the circuit.

[Passive Sign Convention in AC circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention#AC_circuits)